# Manipulating dates in PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to convert a list days, that I'm querying , to weeks in the query listed below

Please advise. Thank you in advice for your help.

Comment: I think you're missing a code block or screenshot (what it should look like?)

Comment: What is the difference between dates on this two images ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first aggregate by `date_trunc('week', ...)` in a subquery, and then compute the delta between adjacent rows in the outer query:

```
select 
    anchor, 
    average,
    100.000 * (1 - lead(average) over (order by anchor) / average) as delta
from (
    select 
        date_trunc('week', day) anchor,
        round(avg(value)) average
    from mytable
    group by date_trunc('week', day)
) t
order by anchor
```